# fill text box on web page through iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

i have one web view, one text box and button in UIView,

web view has open one site in it, which contain's text box and submit button.

when user enter text in UIView's text box and press button in UIView,
text should filled into web view's text box.

is it possible?

Any help would be accepted.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this method on UIWebView:

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

That'll let you execute JavaScript code in your web view, and get the result back in an NSString.